# Coin toss probability calculation

Tags: probability, markov-chains, random-walk

> A gambler bets on coin flips. With each flip, he wins $1$ dollar with probability $p$, and loses $1$ dollar with probability $1-p$. He starts with $2$ dollar and stops when he reaches either $0$ or $5$ dollar.
>
> 1. What is the probability that the gambler has $\$5$ in the end?
> 2. What is the expected number of coin flips he bets on?

Ok, so basically my assumption towards these question is that:

- Since $p$ and $1-p$ have been specified, its a biased coin.
- The steps are $0$ to $5$, and it starts from step $2$.

Could anyone please confirm or maybe write down your answers if this is correct? or if I have left out any answers could any experts please help me with this question? Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transition matrix for your [absorbing Markov chain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_Markov_chain) is

$$P=
\begin{bmatrix}
 0 & p  & 0 &0&0& 1-p \\
 1-p & 0 & p & 0 & 0&0 \\
 0 & 1-p & 0 & p & 0&0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1-p & 0 & p & 0\\
 0 &0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
 0 &0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{matrix}
\dots$1\\
\dots$2\\
\dots$3\\
\dots$4\\
\dots$5\\
\dots$0\\
\end{matrix}$$

So

$$Q=
\begin{bmatrix}
 0 & p  & 0 &0 \\
 1-p & 0 & p & 0 \\
 0 & 1-p & 0 & p \\
 0 & 0 & 1-p & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$R=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1-p \\
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 \\
p & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and

$$
\begin{align}
N&=(I-Q)^{-1}\\
&=\left(
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1\\
\end{bmatrix}-
\begin{bmatrix}
 0 & p  & 0 &0 \\
 1-p & 0 & p & 0 \\
 0 & 1-p & 0 & p \\
 0 & 0 & 1-p & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}\right)^{-1}\\
&=\left(
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & -p  & 0 &0 \\
 p-1 & 1 & -p & 0 \\
 0 & p-1 & 1 & -p \\
 0 & 0 & p-1 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\right)^{-1}
\end{align}
$$

You can invert this yourself because I'm too tired and lazy.

The point is that $B=NR$ will give you the answer to part 1

And $t=N\mathbf{1}$ will give you the expected number of steps for each starting position - you want the second row value.